# Paypal REST API, how to do?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, paypal

i am quite new in paypal REST API, I'm using php, framework codeigniter.
I'm sorry, i don't quite understand what this means.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

i couldn't find any related thing about how to read this. and how to apply this in php cURL

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this code from github. 
`https://github.com/kidino/paypal_ec` this is very basic and you can easily understand 
and just go through the process of paypal payments steps and API Calls. Here is the documentation.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/

angelleye.com also providing full features for the paypal http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-codeigniter-class-library-for-paypal/

Comment: I've tried the `angelleye` codes. I'm quite having hard time to understand the codes too. the paypal model is a lot of unrecognised patterns.

Comment: please look at the line 272 having the function `function hash_call` https://github.com/kidino/paypal_ec/blob/master/Paypal_ec.php

Comment: here is the another solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729167/paypal-api-with-php-and-curl?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use REST then try this library this works great for all REST APIs

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

Comment: I'm planning to use REST but I'm quite confuse in the codes right now. had any basic codes regarding paypal with this `restclient`?

Comment: check the examples of this library its really easy and i have used it before in my projects