# Paypal get access token with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal

hello i'm using code used by other people who supposedly have gotten it to work and have gotten their token information retrieved. The code is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "myclientid";
$secret = "mysecret";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 6); //NEW ADDITION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json->access_token);
}

curl_close($ch); //THIS CODE IS NOW WORKING!
```

I retrieved this code from [Paypal API with PHP and cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729167/paypal-api-with-php-and-curl) and have seen it implemented in some others peoples code so i assume that it works. However i'm only receiving no response even though i am supplying the correct client id and secret (maybe a recent update has broken this code?).

The guide provided by Paypal on getting the access token is found here-> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ 
however it demonstrates the solution in cURL and not through the PHP cURL extension so its alittle cryptic to me. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it seems that it is now a requirement to declare what type of SSL Version to use, thus the code above will work when `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 6); //tlsv1.2` is inserted.

Answer (score 8):

Just tested the API and I can confirm this code is working :

(No SSL options)

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID.":".$PAYPAL_SECRET,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Accept-Language: en_US"
    ),
    ));

    $result= curl_exec($curl);

    $array=json_decode($result, true); 
    $token=$array['access_token'];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
```